# Java GUI button wont initialize

Tags: java

So i'm creating a program that sort of acts like a calculator for a certain item for sales. I have a calculate button but pressing the button won't initialize the code within it. I am using Swing designer for the gui. Here's the code with the button

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calculate Total");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(37, 1113, 330, 77);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    if(btnNewButton.getModel().isPressed())
    {

        // Sets value for # of gloves per type
        LA = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
        LB = Integer.parseInt(textField_8.getText());
        SA = Integer.parseInt(textField_12.getText());
        SB = Integer.parseInt(textField_13.getText());
        total = LA + LB + SA + SB;

        // Sets value for percentage of gloves compared to total 
        percLA = LA / total;
        percLB = LB / total;
        percSA = SA / total;
        percSB = SB / total;
        double percTotal = percLA + percLB + percSA + percSB;

        //21;
        // Sets value for total # of gloves
        textField_22.setText(Double.toString(total));

        // Sets value for percentage 
        textField_2.setText(Double.toString(percLA));
        textField_7.setText(Double.toString(percLB));
        textField_14.setText(Double.toString(percSA));
        textField_15.setText(Double.toString(percSB));
        textField_21.setText(Double.toString(percTotal));

        // Sets value for cost per pair
        costLA = Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText());
        costLB = Integer.parseInt(textField_6.getText());
        costSA = Integer.parseInt(textField_16.getText());
        costSB = Integer.parseInt(textField_17.getText());  
    }
```

And here's the full code if needed

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Program {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;
private JTextField textField_4;
private JTextField textField_5;
private JTextField textField_6;
private JTextField textField_7;
private JTextField textField_8;
private JTextField textField_12;
private JTextField textField_13;
private JTextField textField_14;
private JTextField textField_15;
private JTextField textField_16;
private JTextField textField_17;
private JTextField textField_18;
private JTextField textField_19;
private JTextField textField_20;
private JTextField textField_21;
private JTextField textField_22;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Program window = new Program();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Program() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1109, 1400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    // Total # of pairs per glove
    double LA = 0;
    double LB = 0;
    double SA = 0;
    double SB = 0;
    double total = 0;

    // Percentage of gloves compared to total
    double percLA = 0;
    double percLB = 0;
    double percSA = 0;
    double percSB = 0;

    // Cost per glove type
    double costLA = 0;
    double costLB = 0;
    double costSA = 0;
    double costSB = 0;


    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_1.setColumns(10);
    textField_1.setBounds(231, 74, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1);


    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setEditable(false);
    textField_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_2.setColumns(10);
    textField_2.setBounds(440, 74, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2);


    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    textField_3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_3.setColumns(10);
    textField_3.setBounds(650, 74, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_3);

    textField_4 = new JTextField();
    textField_4.setEditable(false);
    textField_4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_4.setColumns(10);
    textField_4.setBounds(860, 74, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_4);

    textField_5 = new JTextField();
    textField_5.setEditable(false);
    textField_5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_5.setColumns(10);
    textField_5.setBounds(860, 147, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_5);

    textField_6 = new JTextField();
    textField_6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_6.setColumns(10);
    textField_6.setBounds(650, 147, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_6);

    textField_7 = new JTextField();
    textField_7.setEditable(false);
    textField_7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_7.setColumns(10);
    textField_7.setBounds(440, 147, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_7);

    textField_8 = new JTextField();
    textField_8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_8.setColumns(10);
    textField_8.setBounds(231, 147, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_8);

    textField_12 = new JTextField();
    textField_12.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_12.setColumns(10);
    textField_12.setBounds(231, 219, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_12);

    textField_13 = new JTextField();
    textField_13.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_13.setColumns(10);
    textField_13.setBounds(231, 293, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_13);

    textField_14 = new JTextField();
    textField_14.setEditable(false);
    textField_14.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_14.setColumns(10);
    textField_14.setBounds(440, 219, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_14);

    textField_15 = new JTextField();
    textField_15.setEditable(false);
    textField_15.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_15.setColumns(10);
    textField_15.setBounds(440, 293, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_15);

    textField_16 = new JTextField();
    textField_16.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_16.setColumns(10);
    textField_16.setBounds(650, 219, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_16);

    textField_17 = new JTextField();
    textField_17.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_17.setColumns(10);
    textField_17.setBounds(650, 293, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_17);

    textField_18 = new JTextField();
    textField_18.setEditable(false);
    textField_18.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_18.setColumns(10);
    textField_18.setBounds(860, 219, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_18);


    textField_19 = new JTextField();
    textField_19.setEditable(false);
    textField_19.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_19.setColumns(10);
    textField_19.setBounds(860, 293, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_19);

    textField_20 = new JTextField();
    textField_20.setEditable(false);
    textField_20.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_20.setColumns(10);
    textField_20.setBounds(860, 386, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_20);

    textField_21 = new JTextField();
    textField_21.setEditable(false);
    textField_21.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_21.setColumns(10);
    textField_21.setBounds(440, 386, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_21);

    textField_22 = new JTextField();
    textField_22.setEditable(false);
    textField_22.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    textField_22.setColumns(10);
    textField_22.setBounds(231, 386, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_22);

    Box horizontalBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox.setBounds(213, 74, -187, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox);

    Box horizontalBox_1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_1.setBounds(22, 74, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_1);

    JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("Latex A");
    lblTest.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    horizontalBox_1.add(lblTest);

    Box horizontalBox_2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_2.setBounds(22, 147, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_2);

    JLabel lblLatexB = new JLabel("Latex B");
    lblLatexB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    horizontalBox_2.add(lblLatexB);

    Box horizontalBox_3 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_3.setBounds(22, 219, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_3);

    JLabel lblSyntheticA = new JLabel("Synthetic A");
    lblSyntheticA.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    horizontalBox_3.add(lblSyntheticA);

    Box horizontalBox_4 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_4.setBounds(22, 293, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_4);

    JLabel lblSyntheticB = new JLabel("Synthetic B");
    lblSyntheticB.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    horizontalBox_4.add(lblSyntheticB);

    Box horizontalBox_5 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_5.setBounds(231, 0, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_5);

    JLabel lblPairsYear = new JLabel("Pairs / Year");
    lblPairsYear.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    horizontalBox_5.add(lblPairsYear);

    Box horizontalBox_6 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_6.setBounds(440, 0, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_6);

    JLabel lblOfTotal = new JLabel("% Of Total");
    lblOfTotal.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    horizontalBox_6.add(lblOfTotal);

    Box horizontalBox_7 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_7.setBounds(650, 0, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_7);

    JLabel lblPricePerPair = new JLabel("Price Per Pair");
    lblPricePerPair.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 33));
    horizontalBox_7.add(lblPricePerPair);

    Box horizontalBox_8 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    horizontalBox_8.setBounds(860, 0, 200, 64);
    frame.getContentPane().add(horizontalBox_8);

    JLabel lblTotalSpent = new JLabel("Total Spent");
    lblTotalSpent.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    horizontalBox_8.add(lblTotalSpent);

    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setToolTipText("h");
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 72));
    slider.setBounds(39, 592, 1021, 88);
    frame.getContentPane().add(slider);

    JLabel lblAverageSalePrice = new JLabel("Average Sale Price");
    lblAverageSalePrice.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    lblAverageSalePrice.setBounds(39, 536, 384, 43);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblAverageSalePrice);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    textArea.setBounds(468, 525, 172, 61);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea);

    JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_1.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    textArea_1.setBounds(468, 714, 172, 61);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_1);

    JLabel lblTotalNumberOf = new JLabel("Total Number Of Pairs");
    lblTotalNumberOf.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    lblTotalNumberOf.setBounds(39, 725, 384, 43);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblTotalNumberOf);

    JSlider slider_1 = new JSlider();
    slider_1.setToolTipText("h");
    slider_1.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider_1.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 72));
    slider_1.setBounds(39, 783, 1021, 88);
    frame.getContentPane().add(slider_1);

    JTextArea textArea_2 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_2.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    textArea_2.setBounds(468, 895, 172, 61);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_2);

    JLabel lblPriceReduction = new JLabel("Price Reduction");
    lblPriceReduction.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    lblPriceReduction.setBounds(39, 917, 384, 43);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPriceReduction);

    JSlider slider_2 = new JSlider();
    slider_2.setToolTipText("h");
    slider_2.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider_2.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 72));
    slider_2.setBounds(39, 968, 1021, 88);
    frame.getContentPane().add(slider_2);

    JTextArea textArea_3 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_3.setEditable(false);
    textArea_3.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    textArea_3.setBounds(417, 1129, 292, 61);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_3);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calculate Total");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(37, 1113, 330, 77);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    if(btnNewButton.getModel().isPressed())
    {

        // Sets value for # of gloves per type
        LA = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
        LB = Integer.parseInt(textField_8.getText());
        SA = Integer.parseInt(textField_12.getText());
        SB = Integer.parseInt(textField_13.getText());
        total = LA + LB + SA + SB;

        // Sets value for percentage of gloves compared to total 
        percLA = LA / total;
        percLB = LB / total;
        percSA = SA / total;
        percSB = SB / total;
        double percTotal = percLA + percLB + percSA + percSB;

        //21;
        // Sets value for total # of gloves
        textField_22.setText(Double.toString(total));

        // Sets value for percentage 
        textField_2.setText(Double.toString(percLA));
        textField_7.setText(Double.toString(percLB));
        textField_14.setText(Double.toString(percSA));
        textField_15.setText(Double.toString(percSB));
        textField_21.setText(Double.toString(percTotal));

        // Sets value for cost per pair
        costLA = Integer.parseInt(textField_3.getText());
        costLB = Integer.parseInt(textField_6.getText());
        costSA = Integer.parseInt(textField_16.getText());
        costSB = Integer.parseInt(textField_17.getText());






    }
}
```

}

Update : created an anonymous class for the listener but my code won't initialize for where I place the code for my button to perform. Here's the code

```
    JTextArea textArea_2 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_2.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    textArea_2.setBounds(468, 895, 172, 61);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_2);

    JLabel lblPriceReduction = new JLabel("Price Reduction");
    lblPriceReduction.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 35));
    lblPriceReduction.setBounds(39, 917, 384, 43);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblPriceReduction);

    JSlider slider_2 = new JSlider();
    slider_2.setToolTipText("h");
    slider_2.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider_2.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 72));
    slider_2.setBounds(39, 968, 1021, 88);
    frame.getContentPane().add(slider_2);

    JTextArea textArea_3 = new JTextArea();
    textArea_3.setEditable(false);
    textArea_3.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    textArea_3.setBounds(417, 1129, 292, 61);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea_3);


    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calculate Total");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    btnNewButton.setBounds(37, 1113, 330, 77);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new Action());

}

    static class Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            textArea_1.setText("This is a test"); 
        }
    }


}
```

However where I typed //Trying to place code here, I can't call for example textfield_3.setText();. Nothing will initialize.

Comment: The way to catch a click of a button in swing is to use an ActionListener

Comment: `if(btnNewButton.getModel().isPressed())   {` this will in practice never be true, because it is executed before the button is visible

Comment: That makes sense, thanks to both of you ^. Will look into using ActionListener.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an actionListener to the JButton and implement an actionPerformed method of that interface. Please, take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html and you will get some tips. Your code is just not attached to the button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what the real problem is, but I will recommend you to implement ActionListener in your class so you will have to overwrite the `ActionPerformed` method instead of just using an anonymous class.

This would be the example:

```
public class Programs implements ActionListener{

    // When you create your button
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Calculate Total");
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 43));
    // This line tells the button where the actionListener will be 
    // handlded
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(this);



   //all your code...

   // I will catch all the actions you send me
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     // Here goes the name of the instance, remember that.
     if(e.getSource(btnNewButton)){
        //code to execute when you click the button ...
     }
   }

}
```

The second option would be just adding an anonymous class, I don't recommend this is because the code can get a little dirty.

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        // Code to execute when clicked
      }
    });
```

in this example you don't need to implement ActionListener interface, you just make an anonymous class and internally assing a method.

Good luck, if you have any question i'll be here.

Comment: I do have a question actually, please see the updated part of my post.

Comment: I updated my edit, where I wrote the line about textArea_1 inside my listener class it says in an error "textArea_1 cannot be initialized."  EDIT: Changed textArea to static and now it works.

Comment: I know what the problem is, since that swing components are declared inside your method Java is not sure if it will get instanced so it's asking you to make it static, in this way it doesn't need an instance.
Maybe you should declare it out side the method.

Note: the static works, good luck.